# Does updating urlscan.ini require iisreset?

Tags: iis, urlscan

I'm wondering if I have to do iisreset upon updating the urlscan.ini file. Is this required or will IIS pick up the new ini file immediately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the version of UrlScan. The [UrlScan reference site](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/938/urlscan-3-reference) says:

> UrlScan 3.0 added change notifications for the UrlScan.ini file, so it is no longer necessary to restart IIS after updating your UrlScan.ini file.

Hence, **it does not require to restart IIS.**

Answer (score 1):

in my case URLscan config wasnt loaded until i did reset iis , i have URLScan 3.1 with windows 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5